# ValueError: can't extend empty axis 0 using modes other than 'constant' or 'empty' when extracting features using MFCC

Tags: nlp, speech-recognition, feature-extraction, mfcc

I am working on speech recognition system ,but I am having a problem when I extract the signal features

here is the preprocessing block where i read the audio files and labels and extract the features:

```
audio_path = r"C:\Users\Salma\Downloads\TORGO"
files = os.listdir(audio_path)
all_wave = []
all_label = []
mfcc_features = []
ignored = {"Notes", "phn_arrayMic", "amps", "rawpos", "wavall", "pos", "alignment", "Cpcmd", "EMA", "VIDEO", "wav_headMic", "normpos", "log"}

for file in files:
    for subfile in os.listdir(audio_path + '/'):
        
        for session in [s for s in os.listdir(audio_path + '/' + subfile +'/')if s not in ignored]:
            for subsession in [x for x in os.listdir(audio_path + '/'+ subfile +'/'+ session + '/')if x not in ignored]:
                for data in [y for y in os.listdir(audio_path + '/'+ subfile +'/'+ session + '/' +subsession +'/') if y not in ignored]:
                    
                    waves = [f for f in os.listdir(audio_path + '/' + subfile +'/'+ session +'/' + subsession +'/' + data + '/')if f.endswith('.wav')]
                    labels = [L for L in os.listdir(audio_path + '/' + subfile +'/'+ session +'/' + subsession + '/' + data + '/')if L.endswith('.txt')]

                    for wav in waves:
                        samples, sample_rate = librosa.load(audio_path + '/' + subfile +'/'+ session + '/'+subsession +'/'+ data +'/'+ wav, sr = 16000)
                        samples = librosa.resample(samples, sample_rate, 16000)
                        mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(samples, sample_rate, n_mfcc=13)
                        mfcc = mfcc.T                       
                        all_wave.append(samples)
                        mfcc_features.append(mfcc.tolist())
                    for label in labels:
                        file_path = audio_path + '/' + subfile + '/' + session + '/' + subsession + '/' + data +'/'+ label
                        l = open(file_path, "r")
                        for target in l:
                        
                            all_label.append(target.strip())
```

the code working fine if i removed the mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc

and here is the return error :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-fd45bf295b2c> in <module>
     12                         samples, sample_rate = librosa.load(audio_path + '/' + subfile +'/'+ session + '/'+subsession +'/'+ data +'/'+ wav, sr = 16000)
     13                         samples = librosa.resample(samples, sample_rate, 16000)
---> 14                         mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(samples, sample_rate, n_mfcc=13)
     15                         mfcc = mfcc.T
     16                         all_wave.append(samples)

C:\Users\Salma\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\librosa\feature\spectral.py in mfcc(y, sr, S, n_mfcc, dct_type, norm, lifter, **kwargs)
   1850 
   1851     if S is None:
-> 1852         S = power_to_db(melspectrogram(y=y, sr=sr, **kwargs))
   1853 
   1854     M = scipy.fftpack.dct(S, axis=0, type=dct_type, norm=norm)[:n_mfcc]

C:\Users\Salma\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\librosa\feature\spectral.py in melspectrogram(y, sr, S, n_fft, hop_length, win_length, window, center, pad_mode, power, **kwargs)
   2003         window=window,
   2004         center=center,
-> 2005         pad_mode=pad_mode,
   2006     )
   2007 

C:\Users\Salma\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\spectrum.py in _spectrogram(y, S, n_fft, hop_length, power, win_length, window, center, pad_mode)
   2517                     center=center,
   2518                     window=window,
-> 2519                     pad_mode=pad_mode,
   2520                 )
   2521             )

C:\Users\Salma\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\librosa\core\spectrum.py in stft(y, n_fft, hop_length, win_length, window, center, dtype, pad_mode)
    226             )
    227 
--> 228         y = np.pad(y, int(n_fft // 2), mode=pad_mode)
    229 
    230     elif n_fft > y.shape[-1]:

<__array_function__ internals> in pad(*args, **kwargs)

C:\Users\Salma\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraypad.py in pad(array, pad_width, mode, **kwargs)
    817                 raise ValueError(
    818                     "can't extend empty axis {} using modes other than "
--> 819                     "'constant' or 'empty'".format(axis)
    820                 )
    821         # passed, don't need to do anything more as _pad_simple already

ValueError: can't extend empty axis 0 using modes other than 'constant' or 'empty'
```

so where is could be the problem here and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I meet this same problem, the .m4a audio duration is 280s, however it is only 160KB.
I think it is likely this audio is broken, and you'd better check the audio.

Comment: It was better to write this as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can easily implement MFCC and [here](https://haythamfayek.com/2016/04/21/speech-processing-for-machine-learning.html) has a perfect implementation with complete detail